# Swagger CLI - .NET 6.0, Azure Functions v4 - Having multiple overloads of method 'Configure' is not supported

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0, openapi, swashbuckle

**EDIT** - I've identified what's actually happening & opened a Github issue for it [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2640)

After several days of research - I have been unable to find a reliable answer to this, though I've found several blog sources that have implemented a similar setup using Azure functions - I believe this is possible.

### **Problem**

I am currently trying to generate an `openapiv3.json` using the Swagger CLI & MSBuild so that I can produce a spec file for import into Azure API Mgmt as part of my CI/CD process.

Running the function with the setup outlined below produces the endpoints for `swagger.json` & `openapi/v3.json` - I have successfully used these to import functions into APIM already but I want to produce this spec file as a build artifact so it can be shifted-left and output as an artifact in the CI pipeline so it can be consumed in the CD pipeline - instead of running as a post-deployment task assuming the function made it out & is running in the environment without issue.

I have tried various things - but I always arrive at this error:

```
C:\MyApiFolder [t/238123_OpenApiGen ≡ +1 ~2 -0 !]> dotnet tool run swagger tofile --output openapi.json MyApi/bin/Debug/net6.0/MyApi.dll v1

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Having multiple overloads of method 'Configure' is not supported.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.FindMethod(Type startupType, String methodName, String environmentName, Type returnType, Boolean required)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.FindConfigureDelegate(Type startupType, String environmentName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider hostingServiceProvider, Type startupType, String environmentName, Object instance)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_1.<BuildCommonServices>b__4(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.GetServiceProvider(Assembly startupAssembly) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 145
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_4(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 82
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 59
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 121
```

### **Setup**

I am using

- .NET 6.0
- Azure Functions v4
- `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi` version 1.5.1 - for OpenApi docs
- `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` version 6.5.0

The OpenApi extension above [can be found here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension)

I am trying to utilize the Swagger CLI contained in the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` Nuget package (Version 6.5.0) - this is provided via `AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle` version 3.3.2 I have followed the [instructions here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#using-the-tool-with-the-net-core-30-sdk-or-later) for adding Swashbuckle to my project.

```cs
    [FunctionName("CreateClient")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "CreateClient", tags: new[] { "client", "create" })]
    [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
    [OpenApiRequestBody("application/json", typeof(CreateClient))]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.Created, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "Success Response")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.Conflict, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "Returned when item exists")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "Returned for unhandled errors")]
```

Here is my current iteration of Swashbuckle/Swagger in `Startup.cs` - I have tried this with & without a combination of the three of these registrations.

The `AddSwaggerGen` method is the only one that has remained constant.

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
   // Other registrations

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOpenApiConfigurationOptions, OpenApiConfiguration>()
                        .AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                        .AddSwaggerGen(c => c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiConfiguration().Info))
                        .AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
}
```

I also had to add some items to my `csproj` so the `runtimeconfig.json` is output as part of the build

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

### **Additional Detail**

I am currently utilizing some external Nuget packages that add additional bindings for my functions - these extensions DO contain `Configure` methods that still utilize the `IWebJobsBuilder` so that binding extensions can be added - I have tried removing these - to no avail.

I figured this is worth mentioning.

ex:

```cs
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        => builder.AddExtension<StartupTriggerExtensionConfigProvider>();
```

### **What I have tried**

1. Different Versions of `AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle`.

Version 6.5.0 of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` is targeted at .NET 7.0 & uses some of the binaries there - I was finding that I was getting the same error more immediately when downgrading so I wanted to try and use the latest version.

I was able to do this by introducing a `global.json` & defining the rollforward increment at the solution level:

`global.json`

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "rollForward": "latestMinor",
    "version": "6.0.114"
  }
}
```

This fixes the variance between versions - but brings me back to the error above.

2. Implementing the `SwashbuckleStartup`using an injected `IFunctionsHostBuilder` - this does not work & gets annotated as `[Obsolete]` anyway - so would like to avoid this if possible.
3. Custom Host configuration as [outlined here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#use-the-cli-tool-with-a-custom-host-configuration)

Any recommended workarounds would be awesome.

Comment: Hi, any updates to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I know this is 5 months later - but to my knowledge, there's not a good way to handle the docgen via the dotnet tool. My Github issue is still open. I had to proceed with doing this post-deployment - essentially just making a request to the OpenAPI docgen endpoint to get the output & then import to APIM that way. Note on APIM -   the `az` CLI doesn't establish the APIM backend when using this method so there's an additional task needed to either establish that via Azure PowerShell or to import the function key as a named value & attach it via APIM policy.